# Why does my application freeze when running from the Windows Scheduler?

Tags: delphi

I have a simple application:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

{$R *.res}

procedure Log(text: string);
var
  myFile: textfile;
begin
  AssignFile(myFile, 'my.log');
  if not(FileExists('my.log')) then
    Rewrite(myFile)
  else
    Append(myFile);
  Writeln(myFile, text);
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;

begin
    Log(TimeToStr(Now)+' Passed!');
end.
```

When I try to launch this application via Windows Task Scheduler I have a problem.
  Scheduled task has a status "running" but nothing happens.

Comment: You really should use a complete path. Now you have no idea in what folder the file is created.

Comment: You might be having an IO exception, and your program does not exit.

Comment: What user runs the app. It probably is running in session 0. You'll need to supply your credentials to the task to see it on your desktop.

Comment: I'm assuming access denied, since wherever the application is which calls this would be in a system location. Have you searched your system drive for the file `my.log`?

Comment: Add 'flush (myfile)' before 'closefile'

Comment: @Jerry Dodge Yes, I have. As I understand problem is not that I can not find the log-file, but the fact that application doesn't exit.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Thanks, Andreas. With complete path it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the full path where to save the file. When the Windows task scheduler launches your application, the working directory of your application will be wherever the task scheduler application is located. In turn, Windows is not allowing your application to save a file in that location. Therefore, you must tell it exactly where to save the file.

```
procedure Log(text: string);
var
  myFile: textfile;
  Filename: String;
begin
  Filename:= IncludeTrailingBackslash(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))+'my.log';
  AssignFile(myFile, Filename);
  if not(FileExists(Filename)) then
    Rewrite(myFile)
  else
    Append(myFile);
  Writeln(myFile, text);
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

I'm assuming that Windows is denying access because of your title "freeze". Still, even if the issue isn't access denied, you still don't know where this location is.

Comment: Jerry, Reminder: writing to the folder where the exe is stored is risky because it can be prohibited depending on the security level and Windows version. Wouldn't it be safer store to a less restricted folder - perhaps in AppData or Documents?

Comment: @Robert Yes, this is the point I'm trying to make, but it's not up to me where to save the file, I answered this to fit the OP's specific needs, matching their original code, which suggests they wish it's saved there.